# Master and Slave Databases

Tags: master-slave

On some e-commerce site, an item has only one quantity left. If the item is purchased then the master(used for writes) db will be updated with quantity 0. Since some time lag is involved in master-slave sync, there is a possibility that slave(used for reads) db is not updated when 2nd customer requests information on the same product. He/she might still see stale data, i.e. one quantity available.  Couple of questions are:

1) Is it a good idea to let all the customers related queries hit master database(for updated results)?

2) If not, and master-slave sync will definitely involve some time lag, in this can how can customer experience be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simple case: only single master database.

We both search for product, we both see last item. You buy it. I think about it for 10 seconds more than you do, then click buy. Too late! So I get an error saying "Oops, that item is no longer in stock."

In master/slave it's exact same experience, just the window for it happening is slightly bigger. So really there's nothing you can do to prevent the issue. You don't want all customers doing read queries to master, then. What you want is to do writes through master, and if write fails because of out-of-date state (oops, can't buy) then apologize to the customer.

In the UI for displaying items you can warn users there's only 1 item left, and that will make them expect this error and be less upset when it happens.

Comment: I read this somewhere - one more way to tackle this problem is to divide the reads into critical and non-critical reads. All the reads related to the row which has been updated in last x minutes should hit the master database, else slave database is good enough. However, when any request comes - how can we determine if it is a critical read or not?